# GraphQL format return object

Tags: graphql

Is it possible in GraphQl to not return the data word? I mean instead of this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "firstname": "Alicia",
      "lastname": "Smith"
        }
    }
}
```

return this

```
{
  "user": {
      "firstname": "Alicia",
      "lastname": "Smith"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. GraphQL has a standardized response format. Yours for instance would now allow for any error handling.